# Compare variables from vars file in Ansible in a loop, and replace line if current line in file is different from variable

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I am new to Ansible, and posting in this forum, so please bear with me!

I am trying to iterate through all lines in a file(test_file) and compare lines from variables I put in a vars_file(test.yml), and if the regular expressions of that line matches a variable from test.yml, check if the variables attribute "value" matches. I'm not sure I am explaining this correctly. Here is the files I am trying to describe:

test.yml

```
complexity:
 - { name: 'min_value', expression: '=', value: '10' }
 - { name: 'max_value', expression: '=', value: '100' }
```

test_file

```
min_value = **some random number**
max_value = **some random number**
```

So for example, if the min_value in test_file is 2000, but I want it to be 10, it would replace only the last I guess, attribute of the line. I would like it to iterate through all items in the **complexity** loop in my variables file, and make the necessary changes.

This is what I've tried:

files/test.yml

```
complexity:
 - { name: 'min_value', expression: '=', value: '10' }
 - { name: 'max_value', expression: '=', value: '100' }
test_file: /etc/test/test.conf
file_lines: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/test/test.conf/').splitlines() }}"
```

main.yml

```
 - hosts: localhost
   vars_files: files/test.yml

   tasks:

   - name: Replace line if variables do not match
     lineinfile:
       path: "{{ test_file }}"
       regexp: "{{ item.name }} {{ item.expression }}"
       state: present
       line: "{{ item.name }} {{ item.expression }} {{ item.value }}"
     with_items:
      - "{{ complexity }}"
      - "{{ file_lines }}"
     when: "{{ file_lines }} != {{ item.name }} {{ item.expression }} {{ item.value }}"
```

I've also tried with_nested, and the newer method of with_nested, using a loop:

```
loop: "{{ complexity }} | zip(file_lines) | list }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the file

```ini
shell> cat /tmp/test_file 
min_value = **some random number**
max_value = **some random number**
```

The below play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    complexity:
      - {name: min_value, expression: '=', value: 10}
      - {name: max_value, expression: '=', value: 100}

  tasks:

    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/test_file
        regexp: '^\s*{{ item.name }}\s*{{ item.expression }}\s*(.*)$'
        line: "{{ item.name }} {{ item.expression }} {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ complexity }}"
```

gives abridged (running with --check --diff options)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -CD
  ...
TASK [lineinfile] ****************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/test_file (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test_file (content)
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-min_value = **some random number**
+min_value = 10
 max_value = **some random number**

changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'min_value', 'expression': '=', 'value': 10})
--- before: /tmp/test_file (content)
+++ after: /tmp/test_file (content)
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 min_value = **some random number**
-max_value = **some random number**
+max_value = 100

changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'max_value', 'expression': '=', 'value': 100})
```

The play will modify the file

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
TASK [lineinfile] ****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'min_value', 'expression': '=', 'value': 10})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'max_value', 'expression': '=', 'value': 100})
```

```ini
shell> cat /tmp/test_file 
min_value = 10
max_value = 100
```

The play is idempotent. There are no changes when you repeat it

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
TASK [lineinfile] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'min_value', 'expression': '=', 'value': 10})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'max_value', 'expression': '=', 'value': 100})
```